# Drop Down Menu Disappears Behind Body of Webpage

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, z-index

This has been mentioned before though after two days of trying everything I desperately need help. I've tried changing the z-index but it still shows behind the content though it does appear to be fine on Google Chrome but not Safari? I'm trying real hard to learn CSS so if someone could please explain my answer so that a retarded monkey could understand, that'd be great ! 
[www.whiteboda.com](http://www.whiteboda.com)

Comment: We will need to see your code

Comment: Also, the z-index property doesn't work without position: relative or position: absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You have JavaScript Errors
Click F12 --> Console FIX the JavaScript

for this one
http://www.whiteboda.com/wedding-packages/

Try to play around z-index of with these CSS  class="jqueryslidemenu" or class="sf-menu"
or by ID id="sf-menu"  id="menu-menu-1"

To find that Info I use right click inspect element   (Dev tools F12)
Then you can add CSS and test before update the real one

look into some tutorial of Google DEV tools
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google+Dev+tools

Comment: Ok thanks heaps. I'll try mucking around with that !